How to import / recreate complex material from Blender in Godot?
I ran into an issue when trying to import a complex shader material from Blender to Godot.
Inside Blender 4.0:

Inside Godot 4.3:

I exported it as glTF 2.0, but all the materials result just white.
What am I doing wrong? Are they incompatible and I have to use a Godot shader?

Possibly related question with Godot 3.x.

Game engine renderers generally don't work the same as those in 3DCC tools like Blender, so it's almost never the case that materials are directly portable between them. You will almost always need to make custom materials in your game engine to achieve the right look and performance.

Same question asked in a Blender forum
